# Careers 2.0 - 500 Internal Server Error - Importing from LinkedIn

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, linkedin

I'm trying to import data from my LinkedIn account but when I click the "import this one" button, it dims, but nothing happens. My network tab is reporting a 500 Internal Server Error.

The failing request is to `/cv/updatesection/78166?sectionId=0`

Comment: I got the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report Robbie.  I forgot a XSRF token on that form.  This is fixed now.

Comment: Excellent, it's working for me now. Thanks.

Comment: Please tell how was it fixed?